# Is there a conflict between an Euler's ODE and Rolle's theorem here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, rolles-theorem

Let a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n>2$ or more has $n$ number of distinct non-zero roots then we can prove that
the equation $$x^2f''(x)+3xf'(x)+f(x)=0~~~~(1)$$
has at least $n$ real root.

Let $g(x)=x f(x)$, then $g(x)=0$ also has $n+1$ distinct roots. By Rolle's theorem $g'(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)=0$ has at least $n$ number of real roots. This implies that $h(x)=x^2f'(x)+xf(x)=0$ has at least $n+1$. Again by Rolle's theorem $h'(x)=0$ which is nothing but the equation (1)  has at least $n$ number of real roots.

However, Eq. (1) is Euler's ODE whose solution is obtained by using $f(x)=x^\lambda$, as $\lambda=-1$ is a repeated root, we get a non polynomial solution of Eq. (1) as $$f(x)=(C_1+ C_2 \ln x)/x~~~~(2),$$
which  has exactly one real root as $x=e^{-C_1/C_2}$, where $C_1, C_2$ are arbitrary real numbers.

The question is : Do you see a conflict between Euler's ODE and Rolle's theorem with regard to the number of roots of (1)? Any comment is welcome.

**Edit:**

(1) After the the comment of @fwd we now say that the polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ has $n$-distinct real roots.

(2) Yes, as an ODE (1) is valid for $x>0$ in view of its solution (2). Otherwise as a polynomial Eq. it has many roots.

(3) In any case (1) will have at least one root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the equation $(1)$, you are not asserting that it holds for all $x$, but rather we seek values of $x$ for which it holds ( these are the roots). If you were asserting that $(1)$ held for all $x$ in some domain, then it is an ODE that can be solved for $f$ which isn't even a polynomial as you observed.

In addition, you say that if $f(x)$ has $n$ distinct zeros, then $xf(x)$ has $n+1$ distinct roots. How do you know $0$ is not one of the roots of $f$?

Comment: Thanks, you resolved it well, you may see my edit I have modified the title itself. More precisely. The ODE is valid $\forall~  x\in (0,\infty).$ However, one can say that $f(x)$ in any case has at least one root.